# Is there a way to stay in a coroutine until a condition is met?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to program a very simple dialogue system.  When a player gets a dialogue box, the box remains until they press a key.  Then a second dialogue box appears.  Again, they press a key, and so on.

I am realizing, however, that my method of using coroutines doesn't work, because every dialogue box displays at once. Using a simplified version:

```
IEnumerator Test() {
        //Code that displays a message
        yield return StartCoroutine(WaitForKey(KeyCode.Space));
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForKey(KeyCode keyCode)
    {
        while (!Input.GetKeyDown(keyCode))
            yield return null;
    }

    void start(){
        StartCoroutine(Test());
        StartCoroutine(Test());
    }
```

The results of the above code is that two messages are displayed. Plus, they display immediately--once a condition is met, the process jumps from that courtine to the initiating, runs the next line of code, and periodically returns to the first coroutine to see if it has finished.

How do I get one coroutine to finish before it continues with the rest of the code following it?

Comment: Do you have the dialogue boxes  you want to display in array?  How do you have the dialogue boxes setup in order? This would be helpful for me to help.

Comment: @programmer: I don't have any arrays because it's sort of a case-by-base function.  Currently, any time I want to pop up the message I use this:
`StartCoroutine(dh.showMessage ("NameOfSpeaker", "Stuff I am saying"));`

Comment: That's just it; I don't know the text in advance. I am also not familiar with how to create canvases yet. I definitely appreciate all the help, especially all the code you supplied, but I am slow to respond because I am still trying to parse it.

Comment: I know how to do everything except create an array of canvases.  Also doesn't this make reading text out of a file difficult for dialogues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to go about this is to creates arrays of Canvas as dialog. Disable all of them in the Editor. With the code below, you can **change** the array **size** of the **dialogueGameObjectCanvas** to how many dialogues you have then assign the parent of each dialogues in order to the **dialogueGameObjectCanvas** array in the Editor. Cancas must be the parent of each dialogue. Run it.

Pressing the space bar will go to the next dialogue. This is the easiest way.

Now, for the pro way. If the **dialogue** is **generated** during **run time**, you can use **List** to **add** or **remove** dialog(GameObjectUICanvas)instead of using array to do it. You can easily convert array to List and that should work for **dynamically** generated dialogues.

`startDisplayDialogue()` starts the dialogue.

`isDialogueDisplaying()` tells you if the dialogue is currently displayed on the screen.

`getDialogueCurrentNumberDisplaying()` gets the current array number of dialogue disaplying

`stopDisplayDialogue()` kills the whole dialogue and closes them.

Remember that `startDisplayDialogue()` is coroutine function and must be started with `StartCoroutine (startDisplayDialogue ());`

```
public GameObject[]dialogueGameObjectCanvas;
bool isRunning = false;
int dialogNumberDisplaying = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    //animationSprite = new GameObject[5]; Uncomment if you want to assign through code, otherwise assign the dialogues from the Editor
    StartCoroutine (startDisplayDialogue ());
}

//Display the first dialogue then wait for the space to be pressed then display the next dialue
IEnumerator startDisplayDialogue ()
{
    //Make sure there is only one instance of the dialuge functionr running. Break if there is alread one running 
    if (isRunning) {
        yield break;
    } else {
        isRunning = true;
    }

    int dialogueNumber = 0; //Starts from 0 to the size of the animationSprite array
    dialogNumberDisplaying = dialogueNumber;

    while (isRunning) {
        //Stop if the dialogNumber is >= number of dialogues to dispaly(dialogue arrays)
        if (dialogueNumber >= dialogueGameObjectCanvas.Length) {
            isRunning = false;
            //dialogueGameObjectCanvas [dialogueNumber].SetActive (false);
            Debug.Log ("End of dialogue");
            yield break;
        }

        //Dispaly the current Dialogue based on the array number
        dialogueGameObjectCanvas [dialogueNumber].SetActive (true);

        //Wait until the Space bar is pressed 
        while (!Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            yield return null; //Must wait here or else Unity would freeze
        }

        //Space bar has been pressed. Disable the current Dialogue then increement dialogueNumber so that then the next one in the array will display
        dialogueGameObjectCanvas [dialogueNumber].SetActive (false);
        dialogueNumber++;
        dialogNumberDisplaying = dialogueNumber; //For the getDialogueCurrentNumberDisplaying function


        //Check if stopDisplayDialogue is called then exit
        if (!isRunning) {
            dialogueGameObjectCanvas [dialogueNumber].SetActive (false);
            yield break;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}

//Check if a dialogue is currently displaying
bool isDialogueDisplaying ()
{
    return isRunning;
}

//Get the current array number of dialogue currently displaying
int getDialogueCurrentNumberDisplaying ()
{
    return dialogNumberDisplaying;
}

//Stops the dialogue from displaying
void stopDisplayDialogue ()
{
    isRunning = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are calling `StartCoroutine(Test())` twice in the same frame, only when you use 
`yield return StartCouroutine(Test());` 
will the next line wait until the coroutine finishes to be executed.

So right now your start function will run the `Test()` functions until it gets it first yield return X, and then it will go back to the second line of the Start function and do the same thing.  Then in the next frame (or whenever your yield return X finishes) it will continue executing those routines.

To solve your problem you could do a `while(true)` in your Test function if i understand what you are doing.  However, if you post more detailed code I can give you a better suggestion as to why your approach isnt working the way you expect!

Comment: If I understand correctly, if I use while(true), either both functions will still play at the same time, or neither will play.That is, if I use while(!Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.Space)), then when the first Test() initiates the loop, the coroutine will kick it out and start the second Test(), which will start a second loop.  Then both functions will have been played simultaneously again, instead of just the first Test() playing to completion, then the second Test(); playing until completion.

Comment: Yea the only way to prevent both from running at the same time is to start another coroutine that does `yield return StartCoroutine(Test())` twice within that coroutine.  You also have the option of making Start() be 'IEnumerator Start()' instead of 'void Start()' which will make start be a coroutine automatically, allowing you to do 'yield return StartCoroutine(Test())' inside Start.

Comment: You also may want to do `Input.ResetInputAxes();` at the end of the WaitForKey function if you notice the other box getting dismissed right away

Comment: can you possibly give me an example of the `yield return StartCoroutine(Test()` solution?  I am not sure i follow

Comment: Basically from within any coroutine you can yield return starting another coroutine, and that will wait for the coroutine you just started to finish before executing the next line.